# how can I hide the default methods of Object when creating a new instance

Tags: javascript, object, methods, tostring, prototype-programming

I would like to hide all the default methods like toString, hasOwnProperty, valueOf etcetera when creating an instance. How is this possible?

```
function Foo() {};
var x = new Foo();
x.toString(); //should fail
```

And additionaly; I can understand that if I do this, I cannot do the following:

```
console.log(x);
```

But what else is using these functions?

Comment: Even assuming you are able to do this, why do you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to you could write over the `toString` method:

```
    Foo.prototype.toString = undefined;
```

Comment: can I do that for all of these methods or is the environment depending on any of them?

Comment: That depends on what you plan to use these objects with.  Are you going to be using them with any third party utilities?

Comment: @coen - then I'm guessing you'll be fine

Comment: That doesn't overwrite the *toString* method, it just places a *toString* property on the property resolution chain that "shaddows" *Object.prototype.toString*. Incidentally, the identifier "undefined" is treated as an undeclared variable, hence assignment of *undefined*. If someone was to assign a value to *undefined*, then that value would be assigned. To be clear, you could just do:  `Foo.prototype.toString;` and not assign any value.

Comment: @Rob - so just saying Foo.prorotype.toString; would similarly hide the toString() method?  I tried that - it doesn't seem to affect toString() at all

Comment: I don't understand this part: 'you could just do .....'. Do that to achieve what?

Comment: @coen—Sorry, my mistake. You have to assign a value to create the property, consider using in IIFE that returns undefined: `Foo.prototype.toString = (function(){}());`. However, doing that means if you do `alert(x)` you will get a type error as `alert` will attempt to call `x.toString`, which isn't callable.

Comment: @Rob, setting it to an immediate invocation of a function that returns nothing (undefined) is cool, but if `undefined` were really treated as an undeclared variable, wouldn't that whole line fail?  I put `Foo.prototype.toString = LALALA;` and I got an error right there that `LALALA was not defined`.  When I set `Foo.prototype` to undefined, everything worked as expected.

Comment: @AdamRackis - yes, bad day. There is a property of the global object called 'undefined' whose initial value is undefined. It's not read–only though so it can be assigned a value (though of course doing so isn't a good idea).

Comment: @RobG - ahh - yeah, I did know that you could (stupidly) re-assign undefined.  I guess *that's* why setting Foo.prorotype.toString to the result of that immediately executing function was preferable.